Front Passenger Carpet Soaked From Car Wash
2008 Honda Accord6 Cylinder Sedan with 155k miles.
After any car wash, my front passenger footrest or carpet gets soaked with soap and water.
I checked and cleaned Sunroof drain with air compressor, mechanic lifted car and couldn’t find any visible damage but he also used air compressor on some drain, and I changed my dirty clogged cabin air filter as well.
Issue persists, please advise on any thing I should check.

You said you cleaned the sunroof drain with air compressor, but did you test it for water flow after? Very highly likely the water leakage is from your sunroof somewhere. This is the most logical and obvious place for it to be from.

Like Paulster said! Perhaps you could get someone to shoot compressed air into the sunroof drain while you get your head down in the footrest area to listen for the hiss. That's likely where the water is leaking into the passenger compartment.

i found that the cabin air filter also got wet after the car wash and the leak to the front passenger
